# Polkadot runtime upgrade mechanism and voting

Tags: polkadot, runtime-upgrade

according to substrate docs:

```
To perform a forkless runtime upgrade, Substrate uses existing runtime logic to update the Wasm runtime stored on the blockchain to a new consensus-breaking version with new logic. This upgrade gets pushed out to all full nodes on the network as a part of the consensus process. After the Wasm runtime is upgraded, the orchestration engine sees that the native runtime spec_name, spec_version, or authoring_version no longer matches the new Wasm runtime. As a result, the orchestration engine executes the canonical Wasm runtime instead of using the native runtime in any of the execution processes.
```

Question:
Is there any voting system that decides whether to publish this new update or discard it? if yes then how does that voting works?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, runtime upgrades need to pass by referendum (i.e. voted on by all DOT holders). The majority of stake always commands the network. There is in fact a Referendum right now to upgrade Polkadot to runtime v9250, see: https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/referendum/69

for details or you can vote on it yourself [here](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fpolkadot.api.onfinality.io%2Fpublic-ws#/democracySee)

for the details of how this works have a look to [this doc page](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-governance#referenda)

credits:
Bill|W3f